# ValueAnimator during activity transition doesn't work

Tags: android

I want to achieve an effect of doing an activity transition where the user can see the previous activity while the transition is happening. As far as I understand, using overridePendingTransition(enterAnim, exitAnim) can achieve this effect, but these animations must be xml files that affect the entire activity (e.g. sliding the entire activity in), but I have a navigational bar that I want to be fixed, so this solution won't work. I also can't make my activities translucent because these animations would ideally be used in the entire app.

What I realized after playing with transitions is that even if you don't specify an activity to be translucent, the Android OS will let you see the previous activity while a transition is happening (e.g. a slide animation on an activity will let you see the previous activity while the slide happens). So I tried setting an "empty transition" by using overridePendingTransition(R.id.keep, R.id.keep) where R.id.keep references an anim xml which is a fade from 1.0 alpha to 1.0 alpha, and doing a view animation in a ValueAnimator in the onCreate of the next activity. The idea is that while the activity transition happens, the OS will let you see the previous activity, and we can take advantage of this time frame of transparency by doing a ValueAnimator on the view of the next activity (after the activity transition happens, the OS won't let you see the previous activity and will show a black screen even if you set the window background colour to be transparent, but the ValueAnimator finishes before that).

The technique I used above works well on Nougat, but it seems for API 23 and below, the UI doesn't change during the empty activity transition even though a ValueAnimator is running, and the ValueAnimator can only update the UI after the activity transition finishes. I didn't really expect this behaviour, so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Admittedly my way of doing view-level animations while being able to see the previous activity is a bit hacky, does anyone know a better way of achieving the effect I want, or some insight into why my technique works on Nougat but not on API below that?

Comment: I suppose that migrating to fragments is not an option? With fragments you'd have complete control over transitions